# Spread operator not working in method map in Express.js

Tags: javascript

I get data from database using sequelize in Express.js query:

```
const users = await models.users.findAll({
  deleted: 0,
});
```

Returned this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "logo": "1588863296261.png",
    }
]
```

Now I need add full adress to `"logo"`:

> http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/logo/1588863296261.png

So I using method `map`:

```
const dataUsers = users.map(user => ({
    ...user,
    logo: user.logo ? `http://${req.headers.host}/public/logo/${user.logo}` : null,
}));

res.status(200).json(dataUsers);
```

`dataUsers` return null Object, but when I remove spread operator and I replace it with this:

```
id: user.id,
name: user.name,
description: user.description,
logo: user.logo ? `http://${req.headers.host}/public/logo/users/${user.logo}` : null,
```

Then it work correctly. Why spread operator does not work in this example ?

Comment: `user` is a sequelize model instance that has a lot of stuff in it. For instance properties might be defined higher in prototype chain. Try `...user.toJSON()`;

Comment: Yes, it's works, thank you. You can write answer, I will approve it.